# Next.js with multiple fonts using Material UI

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I want to use multiple fonts with Material UI in my Next.js project. I am sharing my customeTheme.js:

```javascript
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Roboto, Poppins, Bungee_Spice } from "next/font/google";

export const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
  weight: ["400", "600", "800"],
});

export const bungee_spice = Bungee_Spice({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
  weight: ["400"],
});

const customTheme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    // fontFamily: bungee_spice.style.fontFamily, // This works
    fontFamily: {
      customFontOne: bungee_spice.style.fontFamily,
      customFontTwo: poppins.style.fontFamily,
    }, // This is not working
  },
});

export default customTheme;
```

I want to use these custom fonts like:

```javascript
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";


export default function Home() {
  return (
      <Box>
        <Typography sx={{ fontFamily: "customFontOne" }}>
          THIS IS A ROBOTO FONT this is a roboto font
        </Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ fontFamily: "customFontTwo" }}>
          THIS IS A POPPINS FONT this is a poppins font
        </Typography>
      </Box>
  );
}
```

How can I use different fonts in different lines?